# Permission denied when run casperjs in iron.io

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, iron.io, ironworker

I'm testing casperjs in iron.io as this example

https://github.com/iron-io/iron_worker_examples/blob/master/binary/casperjs/googlelinks.js

but when iron_worker complete this task, it gives an error message

> ./run.sh: 2: ./run.sh: casperjs/bin/casperjs: Permission denied

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in run.sh:

```
..
chmod +x casperjs/bin/casperjs
..
```