# CasperJS and IronWorker : unrecognized option `--ssl-protocol=any'

Tags: ssl, casperjs, chmod, ironworker

I've just started to mess around with CasperJS and IronWorker and was first blocked by this error when trying to queue a worker :

`./run.sh: 2: ./run.sh: casperjs/bin/casperjs: Permission denied`

This issue has already been documented and solved here :
[Permission denied when run casperjs in iron.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449084/permission-denied-when-run-casperjs-in-iron-io)

But using `chmod +x` doesn't work when I need to launch casperjs with options :

`chmod +x casperjs/bin/casperjs example.js --ssl-protocol=any`

Resulting in :
`chmod: unrecognized option '--ssl-protocol=any'` for more information.

Is it impossible to pass options to CasperJS in IronWorker ? If so, is there another way to open pages with SSL protection ?

Thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chmod` only needs a file name as argument - since it modifying file attributes.

Try it:

```
chmod +x casperjs/bin/casperjs
casperjs/bin/casperjs example.js --ssl-protocol=any
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! Made a little difference, but the worker still fails with this error : `chmod: cannot access 'casperjs/bin/casperjs\r': No such file or directory ./run.sh: 2: ./run.sh: casperjs/bin/casperjs: Permission denied`

Comment: Ok, this last error happened because of line endings in the shell script... Shame on me for using Windows... Answer accepted, thank you thousandsofthem !